# Mysql IN absurdamente lento, como refactorizarlo

Tags: mysql

Tengo una consulta asi

```
SELECT destinationCode 
FROM destinations 
WHERE destinationCode NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT(destinationCode) FROM hotels
);
```

Que es absurdamente lenta.

Lei que mysql hace evalua la subquery IN por cada row.

Como se les ocurre refactorizar esto? No lo veo con inner joins

Comment: cuántas filas tiene la tabla `hotels`?, cuáles son los índices de ambas tablas?

Comment: hotels tiene 100.000 registros. Los indices son solamente para el id y otro para identificar el hotel con el id de un api. los dos campos enteros. Lo mismo para las destinations

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a hacer un *left join is null*?

```
SELECT destinations.destinationCode FROM destinations LEFT JOIN hotels ON destinations.destinationCode = hotels.destinationCode WHERE hotels.destinationCode IS NULL;
```

Creo que también podría ayudar a que vaya más ágil si agregas ese campo como index de la tabla...

Comment: es mas rapido, sigue siendo lento pero para mis propositos basta!

Comment: yo probaría a poner el campo destinationCode como índice, para que vaya más rápido la consulta